# How is this line of code is evaluated in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on the android developer tutorial "[Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#nonsticky)"

Everything was ok until I found this code snippet.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

I'm a little bit confused with the `setSystemUiVisibility(int)` method because I don't know how this condition is evaluated.

Why is this method receiving several integer values?

Maybe it is a very basic concept about java language but I had never used or seen it before.

Comment: All of those values are OR'd together, then passed to `setSystemUiVisibility` as a single integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setSystemUiVisibility` is actually receiving 1 integer. What you're seeing here are **bit flags**. All those `View` constants you see are combined using bitwise or.

The idea is that a flag represents a toggle: on or off, 1 or 0. A typical way of representing that is with a `boolean` which has values `true` and `false`. But a `boolean` takes up 4 bytes (for simplicity), which is 32 bits. Well, this `boolean` could actually be used to represent 32 different flags then, with 32 places for 1 or 0! Same with an integer (of size 4 bytes). So lets use an integer to hold a bunch of flags, and set all of them to 0 initially.

We can then use the bitwise or operator (`|`, note 1 bar, not 2) to specify which bit flag to set to "true" like so:

```
00000000 | 00100000 = 00100000
00100000 | 00000001 = 00100001
```

The second number is showing which flag we want to set as true. Now your variables have the values (from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)):

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE          = 0x0100 = 0000 0001 0000 0000
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION = 0x0200 = 0000 0010 0000 0000
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN      = 0x0400 = 0000 0100 0000 0000
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION        = 0x0002 = 0000 0000 0000 0010
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN             = 0x0004 = 0000 0000 0000 0100
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE              = 0x0800 = 0000 1000 0000 0000
```

When you combine them all together with bitwise or, you get `0000 1111 0000 0110` = `0x0F06` = 3846.

Note: I'm not representing 32 bits for simplicity and readability's sake. All the binary numbers I wrote should have leading 0's, in case that was confusing.